# caffe lmdb error: MDB_VERSION_MISMATCH

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe, lmdb

I converted my hdf5 dataset using the following python script:

```
files = os.listdir(args.dir)
new_db = lmdb.open(args.output, map_size=10 ** 10)

for f in files:
    print("processing: " + f)
    X_hit, X_info, y = get_data(f)
    with new_db.begin(write=True) as txn:
        N = X_hit.shape[0]
        n_channels = X_hit.shape[-1]
        img_size = X_hit.shape[1]
        for i in range(N):
            # save only the shape
            el = X_hit[i, :, :, :]
            datum = array_to_datum(el, int(y[i, 1]))
            str_id = '{}_ID{:08}'.format(f, i)

            txn.put(str_id.encode('ascii'), datum.SerializeToString())
new_db.close()
```

but when I use it to train my network with caffe I obtain the following error:

```
F0809 14:18:24.432262 37669 db_lmdb.hpp:53] Check failed: mdb_status == 0 (-30794 vs. 0) MDB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch
```

I checked the LMDB version used by the python lmdb library and caffe and they are both 0.9.18.

Is there something with the python script?

Comment: According to a Symantec documentation at: https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH244130.html, "This issue is related to an inconsistency in the RPM (RedHat Package Manager) database lock files", and the proposed solution is to clean up the RPM lock files, run rm -f var/lib/rpm/__db.*  from the CPM Unix prompt. The files will be recreated automatically by the system. Please check if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer but I think the two problems are unrelated. My problem is about LMDB while the Symantec documentation talks about an RPM problem. The error codes are also slightly different.

Comment: Yes, but I think some kind of database update is a possible candidate of solution for your case too, though I can't comment any further :)

Comment: Perhaps you should re-create your database, as it's explained here:
"the version of the LMDB library doesn't match the version that created the database environment." Perhaps your database is created with another version.
http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/lmdb-lolevel
Though this is only a speculation.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the `MDB_VERSION_MISMATCH` error myself recently and so posting the results of my investigation for posterity.

Looking at the [lmdb source code](https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb/tree/mdb.master/libraries/liblmdb), there are only two cases when `MDB_VERSION_MISMATCH` is reported:

1. Version in the database (or environment?) metadata is different from that of the library used.
2. The lock data format in the lock file is different from the format used/understood by the library.

Let's start with the first one.

### Data Version

The `MDB_DATA_VERSION` macro in the source code, with which the value from the environment/database is compared, is actually not the version of the library. This macro can only have two values:

- `999`, meaning "development version".
- `1`, for everything else.

What this means in practice is that it is extremely unlikely that the error you are seeing being reported is because of Data Version mismatch. Which brings us nicely to the second place where this error is reported: lock format.

### Lock Format

Now, the macro `MDB_LOCK_FORMAT` is *a lot* more complicated and here is the comment, directly from the code, about it:

```
     *  This *attempts* to stop liblmdb variants compiled with conflicting
     *  options from using the lockfile at the same time and thus breaking
     *  it.  It describes locking types, and sizes and sometimes alignment
     *  of the various lockfile items.
     *
     *  The detected ranges are mostly guesswork, or based simply on how
     *  big they could be without using more bits.  So we can tweak them
     *  in good conscience when updating #MDB_LOCK_VERSION.
```

So, basically, if you have created the database environment with one version of the library, you can't access the environment with the version of the library with incompatible lock format **at the same time**.

In my case, due to a crash in one process I was using to read/write the database, I had some stale readers left around and so could not access the data using other tools, which were compiled with different options.

The solution, I think, is to clear the stale readers. This can only be done with the version of the library compatible with the DB -- most likely the one that was used when the process crashed.

[mdb_stat -rr](https://manpages.org/mdb_stat) or [lmdb.reader_check()](https://lmdb.readthedocs.io/en/release/#lmdb.Environment.reader_check) are both should be good options.

In my case the databases were short-lived, so the problem basically went away before I could test any of these solutions, but if I encounter this problem again, I'll update the answer.